# Get time from pressed button (hold pressed)

Tags: ios, nsdate, nstimeinterval

When trying to get the time, I am not getting the expected value.

When I ran this, the time was 19:59. And in the timeDifferenceString, the Value was 71976.894206.
I think that this is the current time.
I calculate 
 71976 / 3600 = 19,99 h 
0,99 * 60 = 59,4 m 
0,4 * 60 = 24 s 
 
So I get the time 19:59:24 o'clock. But I want get the difference between the first time and the second time and not  the current time in seconds.

I want only get the time when I (hold) pressed the button 
and the time that the button is not pressed 
 (by starting the first time if I press on the button and stopped if I press on an other button).

```
- (IBAction)pressTheButton:(id)sender {
NSDate * now = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"hh:mm:ss:SSS"];
NSString *currentTime = [formatter stringFromDate:now];    

NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *components; //= [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
[components setHour:10];

NSDate* firstDate = [NSDate date];
NSString *getTime = [formatter stringFromDate:now];

getTime = [formatter stringFromDate:firstDate];

if (iX==0)
{
    components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
    firstDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
    getTime = [formatter stringFromDate:firstDate];
    //firstDate = [NSDate date];//[dateFormatter dateFromString:@"00:01:00:090"];
}

components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:now];
//NSDate* secondDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"10:01:02:007"];
NSDate * secondDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
getTime = [formatter stringFromDate:firstDate];

NSTimeInterval timeDifference = [firstDate timeIntervalSinceDate:secondDate];
NSString *timeDifferenceString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", timeDifference];

timeDiff[iX] = [timeDifferenceString intValue];
[timeLabel setText:timeDifferenceString];
iX++;
}
```

If you have a better solution for my problem pleas help me.

Comment: How are you connecting this function to the button?

Answer (score 2):

Look at UIControlEventTouchDown, UIControlEventTouchUpInside here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Then I suppose you want to store an NSDate of when you pressed down in some sort of ivar or property (UIControlEventTouchDown) and another one when you release the button (UIControlEventTouchUpInside or UIControlEventTouchUpOutside) and then call -timeIntervalSinceDate: on that date. So it would look roughly like this:

```
- (IBAction)pressedDown:(id)sender {
    self.pressedDownDate = [NSDate date];
}

- (IBAction)touchedUp:(id)sender {
    NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
    NSLog(@"Time passed: %d", [now timeIntervalSinceDate:self.pressedDownDate]);
}
```

Comment: And how I get the time, if the button is released after the button is the first time pressed?

Comment: I need the timeDifference in seconds. Like I have pressed 3 seconds on the button it should save 3 seconds in an array.
And I need the time that is not pressed. And if I press on a second button (save) it should stop the timer.

What I would do with that:
I take a picture, that ist play an animation so that I have pressed on the button 3 sec pic1 (pressed time) then 6 sec pic 2 (released time) and so on...

Did you understand me?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do, but to determine time passed you can use the same logic, initialise a new date when you want to start 'recording' the time (`touchedUp:` for instance) and store it, then whenever you want to stop recording the time compare the current date to the one you stored in an ivar/property. 

Does that make sense?